# How does the method toString() of the BigInteger class work?

Tags: java, biginteger

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte%5B%5D)) I read that the BigInteger class stores the number in a ByteArray.
The BigInteger class has a method called [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString()) . It returns a string representing the decimal value.

Now I wonder how BigInteger can represent the huge binary number as a decimal number without an overflow error. For example, if my byte array has a length of 64, the most significat bit has a value of 2^512 this value would already be far above the maximum value of any standard datatype.

Basically my question is, what is going on inside the toString() method?

Comment: It's implementing the maths itself, basically. It doesn't try to convert the value into a standard datatype and let *that* implementation do the work - it does the work internally.

Comment: There are BigInteger integer division and modulo operations with which one can convert a BigInteger to character digits.

Comment: Looking at the code it seems to use the Schoenhage algorithm at least. https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/math/BigInteger.java